# Flash ocx again in Windows 10/11

Tags: c++, winapi, flash

I have to support an old project that used to produce some SWF files, I want to render them in a Window.

I found flash installation at [here](https://andkon.com/arcade/install_flash_player.exe) which installs correctly and the viewer is able to play the swf files.

However, on using the ActiveX control IShockwaveFlash

```
#import "progid:ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash"
CComPtr<IShockwaveFlash> p = ... // creates the ActiveX control successfully.
std::wstring xx = ... // the file
_bstr_t x(xx.c_str());
hr = p->put_BackgroundColor(RGB(0,0,255));
hr = p->put_Movie(x);
long fn = 0;
p->Play();
hr = p->get_FrameNum(&fn);
```

All functions succeed but frame num is 0 and I get this output

[image]

It used to work in the past. What am I missing?
The same occurs when doing regsvr32 on flash.ocx. It succeeds and the ActiveX control is created, but it shows an invalid image.

Comment: When I click on the [tag:flash] tag, and then on [Learn more...](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flash/info), there is, among other text, this note: _"It has reached the EOL on December 31st, 2020, and Flash content has been fully blocked displaying a static information icon on January 12th, 2021."_ Scrolling on the tag's description further down, I see there is a picture labeled "Flash death information logo", and it looks like your picture. Maybe the behavior you see is related to the discontinuation/blocking?

Comment: Flash is officially dead, but there is an open-source player called [Ruffle](https://ruffle.rs/).

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes but how can I get the raw frames from ruffle ?

Comment: I don't know if you can, I just found it by searching. This is a major problem in the computer field at the moment – technology considered "obsolete" just disappears at the masters' whim. In any case, "Real Flash player on a recent OS" is not something you will be able to support, so you might need to explain reality to whoever demands that you do it.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes I could get the frames, there is an 'exporter' feature in ruffler.